# ASP.NET Json Cannot deserialize the current JSON arrray

Tags: asp.net, json, razor, model, deserialization

I can't list a json on the razor page, it gives me this problem:

> JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'JsonDisplayASP.Models.ListRates' because the
>   type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize
>   correctly.

Json:

```
[{"from":"USD","to":"AUD","rate":"0.93"},{"from":"AUD","to":"USD","rate":"1.08"}]
```

ratesControtller:

```
public class rates
{
    public rates(string from, string to, double rate)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.rate = rate;
    }

    [JsonPropertyName("from")]
    public string from { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("to")]
    public string to { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("rate")]
    public double rate { get; set; }

public class ListRates
{
    public List<rates> LRates { get; set; }



}
```

index.cshtml:

```
@model JsonDisplayASP.Models.ListRates

        @foreach (var item in Model.LRates)
        {
            var from = item.from;
            var to = item.to;
            var rate = item.rate;
```

How can I do it? She won't let me show her a view

Comment: i think you forgot to include code where you deserialize json, it is really important

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can get values.

```
public class HomeController : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller

 public IActionResult Index()
    {

         List<rates> lrates = new List<rates>();
         var wc = new WebClient();
         var json = wc.DownloadString(@"C:\Users\hugo\source\repos\JsonDisplayASP\JsonDisplayASP\wwwroot\lib\rates.json");
        List<rates> model=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<rates>>(json);


        //var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<rates>(json);


        //return Json(model);
        return  View(model);
    }
```